TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext') - Material UI
I'm using MUI(Material UI) in my project.
Component that I'm trying to use is Button.
Check its official component docs here.
Code in which error is occuring :
import * as React from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Delete';
import SendIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Send';
import ShoppingCartIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ShoppingCart';

export default function IconLabelButtons() {
  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="outlined" startIcon={<ShoppingCartIcon />} sx={{color:'grey'}}>
        Add To Cart
      </Button>
      <Button variant="contained" endIcon={<ShoppingCartIcon />} sx={{ color: 'white', backgroundColor:'grey' }}>
        Add To Cart
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}

Complete error msg :
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at Object.useContext (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:77496:25)
    at useDefaultProps (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:70496:50)
    at useDefaultProps (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:67954:91)
    at SvgIcon (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:68093:96)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:42667:22)
    at updateForwardRef (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:45916:24)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:47977:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:32923:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:32967:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:33024:35)

This code is working fine if I remove startIcon & startIcon options from the Button tag.
Working Code:
import * as React from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Delete';
import SendIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Send';
import ShoppingCartIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ShoppingCart';

export default function IconLabelButtons() {
  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="outlined"  sx={{color:'grey'}}>
        Add To Cart
      </Button>
      <Button variant="contained"  sx={{ color: 'white', backgroundColor:'grey' }}>
        Add To Cart
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}


However, I want to use both the options.
I've installed both mui/material & mui/icons-material deps in the project. Still facing aforementioned issue.
Could anyone from the community help me out to fix this.

If you check the link provided for the official docs.
Its version is 6.1.1.
So I tried to update versions of both the used deps in the project using following command:
npm install @mui/material@latest @mui/icons-material@latest.

Doing this fixed the error.

Conclusion:
Keep a check on the versions of mui/material & mui/icons-material deps. They should match the docs version that you are referring.
